# Stackpanel remove with button click

Tags: c#, button, click

I've put the c# project in a dropbox link because it's quite hard to explain.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8w8horclhfwy4ub/Oefening2.zip

When you open it you will see a map with wastebins(ID) (takes a while to render).
There will be a button Remove wastebin, when that button is pressed the whole stackpanel needs to be removed.

Note: there are 2 stackpanels, the upper one needs to be deleted, taking all his childern with him (the second stackpanel, buttons, labels, etc...)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of silly code should do the trick:

```
        var dc = (sender as Button).Parent as StackPanel;

        (dc.Parent as StackPanel).Children.Remove(dc);
```